# How to make the following plot in square dimension?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
if(any(Test$HQ == 1)) {
smoothScatter(Test$FREQ, Test$AF, nrpoints = 0,
xlab = "FREQ", ylab = "AF")}
```

I would like to know how I can output this plot in square dimension?

I have tried adj asp=1 and theme(aspect.ratio = 1), but they are not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `par(pty = "s")` which forces the plotting region to be square - an example with some sample data from the `smoothScatter` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/smoothScatter):

```
n <- 10000
x1  <- matrix(rnorm(n), ncol = 2)
x2  <- matrix(rnorm(n, mean = 3, sd = 1.5), ncol = 2)
x   <- rbind(x1, x2)

par(pty = "s")
smoothScatter(x, nrpoints = 0)
```

[image]